# Convert values of a dictionary to another dictionary with their counts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
d= {'a':['the','the','an','an'],'b':['hello','hello','or']}
```

I want to convert this dictionary into a nested dictionary with values of a key and their count as follows:

```
d = {'a':{'the':2,'an':2},'b':{'hello':2,'or':1}}
```

I can count the values for a dictionary as follows but unable to turn the values to another dictionary with their counts.

```
length_dict = {key: len(value) for key, value in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` instead:

```
from collections import Counter
{k: dict(Counter(v)) for k, v in d.items()}
```

This returns:

```
{'a': {'the': 2, 'an': 2}, 'b': {'hello': 2, 'or': 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary comprehension using Counter

```
from collections import Counter
{k:{p:q for p,q in Counter(v).items()} for k,v in d.items()}
```

Without using Counter

```
def count_values(v):
    d={}
    for i in v:
        d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1
    return d

{k:{p:q for p,q in count_values(v).items()} for k,v in d.items()}
```

Giving you more options using Pandas(not required) here but still

```
from pandas import Series
df = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,Series(v)) for k,v in d.items() ]))
{c:df[c].value_counts().to_dict() for c in df.columns}
```

Answer (score 1):

d= {'a':['the','the','an','an'],'b':['hello','hello','or']}

I think thig ough to do it :

```
from collections import Counter
new_dict = {}
for k in d.keys():
  aux_counter = Counter(d[k])
  new_dict [k] = {}
  for c, v in zip(aux_counter.keys(), aux_counter.values()):
    new_dict[k][c] = v
```